# Convert Classic ASP if statement to PHP

Tags: php, asp-classic

Am new to php and was wondering if anyone could help me convert a classic asp if statement into php:

```
<img src="<%If rsRecordset.Fields.Item("image1").Value <> "" then response.write
(replace(rsRecordset.Fields.Item("image1").Value,".jpg","_small.jpg"))Else response.write
("images/NoPic.jpg")End if%>" width="50" height="40" border="0">
```

php line is like this at the moment:

```
<img src="<?php echo $row_rsAdminMenu['image1']; ?>">
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Frank

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the if statement, may be easier for us to answer

Comment: ASP statement looks to see if image1 exists, if not it display a static 'no-pic.jpg' image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
if ($row_rsAdminMenu['image1']) {
    $src = $row_rsAdminMenu['image1'];
    $src = str_replace('.jpg', '_small.jpg', $src);
} else {
    $src = 'images/NoPic.jpg';
}
echo '<img src="' . htmlspecialchars($src, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . '" />';
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel works really well for me, just one question, why the htmlspecialchars etc in the echo string?

Comment: To prevent HTML injection vulnerabilities if somehow, someone injects HTML into the "image1" column in your database.  Trust me, this happens.